# Determinants and row switching

Tags: linear-algebra

I am confused on how the answer is correct for the following image: [image]

They didn't really switch rows, but just put the first row on the bottom of the matrix. I know that the negative sign on a determinant is determined by how many times the # of rows was switched. Why do are they multiplying by $100$ though? I just don't understand the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Notice how it says "if $\det(A)=100$...".  So it is assumed already that $\det(A)=100$.  The sign change is then determined as you said by how many row switches there are.  You multiply $100=\det(A)$ by $(-1)^{\text{# of sign changes}}$ to get $\det(B)$.  Switching rows $1$ & $2$, then $2$ & $3$, then $3$ & $4$, and so on down to rows $n-1$ & $n$, makes a total of $n-1$ row switches, hence a factor of $(-1)^{n-1}$.

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks